# Uploading images to server but they are not showing up

Tags: php, apache

Pretty much I am following this [tutorial](http://geekonjava.blogspot.com/2014/03/upload-image-on-server-in-android-using.html) to upload images to a localhost server. There are some minor changes I made like this line.

From:

```
upLoadServerUri = "http://10.0.2.2/uploads/UploadToServer.php";
```

To:

```
upLoadServerUri = "http://The IPv4 Address/uploads/UploadToServer.php";
```

Also the Apache file `httpd.conf` had to be changed to the following since I was getting permission error.

From:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I am not even sure if that's safe or not.

The upload/communication seems to work fine but when I check the `www/uploads` folder there are no images. I don't know if I missed any other apache setting or maybe something else, but hopefully someone can direct me.

Comment: Is the response `success` or `fail`?

Comment: The response is `success` with `HTTP Response is : OK: 200`

Comment: You should do a `var_dump()` to find out if/where it's writing. In particular look at `DataOutputStream dos = null`

Comment: The php code should be uploading the images to `uploads/` since it has been specified `$file_path = "uploads/";`

Comment: Strange I selected another picture with smaller size and it worked just fine. The size of the picture seems to effect it, I feel silly now. Thanks for your feedback though!

Comment: I guess if you can help me upload any size image that would answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum size that your script currently allows is:

```
int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;  // 1048576 bytes (1 MB)
```

So if you wanted to upload larger images for example change to something like:

```
int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1536 * 1536;  // 2359296 bytes (2.25 MB)
```

Your php configuration might need to be set to allow images > size to be changed as well.

Comment: I have been playing with maxBufferSize changing it from left to right, that didn't seem to do it. Where do I change the php configuration for bigger size? The php code provided in the tutorial doesn't have restrictions in terms of size, +1 though!

Comment: Yes, the code in the tutorial is what I've shown above; the file gets read into the buffer and saved. The php settings would be in `php.ini`. If you have shell access to your server you can quickly check it by: `cat php.ini | grep upload`

Comment: I am not sure how to run the shell for php, where is it at?

Comment: I opened the php.ini and I saw `output_buffering = 4096` is this what I should be changing?

Comment: I think your answer is very satisfying, I am happy with it at this stage. I am able to upload larger pictures now, but very high quality pictures still don't get uploaded, not a big deal for now. I can dig deeper into it some other time, but for now I appreciate you help.

Comment: @Ammar, What size are the images you are trying to upload? (MB)

Comment: The size is `3088 KB` and resolution is `3264x2448`. I have another picture with the same resolution but less size `2773 KB` and it gets uploaded fine.

Comment: Change the script to `int maxBufferSize = 1 * 2048 * 2048;`. This should allow files that are up to `4 MB` (4096 KB) to be uploaded.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if you've hit the limit for what your `php.ini` file is set to allow. You can also check the `upload_max_filesize` by creating a new page with `<?php phpinfo();?>` and save as `phpinfo.php` — delete it when you're done looking at the values.

Comment: Here is what might be related `post_max_size =3M` , `upload_max_filesize = 64M` , `Command buffer size = 4096`, `output_buffering = 4096`, however I didn't find `max_upload_size`

Comment: According to your configuration you should be able to upload a file up to 64 MB. Check `post_max_size`, that is probably what is limiting it now.

Comment: You are 100% right, I changed it in the `php.ini` file to 4M and it worked like a charm. Much appreciation to you. If you can update your answer, that would be helpful to others.